# Open Toast Notification when Reminder pops up in windows phone 8

Tags: notifications, windows-phone-8

In windows phone 8, clicking on Reminder does not navigate to your app if the phone is locked or if your App Page is opened.
I was thinking if we also open a Toast Notification when the reminder pops up, cause Toast notifications work on lock screens.
i.e. Tapping over the reminder and then unlocking should take the user to the target app, just as toast notifications do.
The only issue is when to schedule a toast notification to open at the scheduled time just like reminders.
Any suggestions or ideas on the same, or any code snippets to resolve the same. Please want help on this badly.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't tap on a reminder over lock screen, a disappointing limitation that applies to 1st party reminders as well. Tapping on a reminder when the phone is already unlocked definitely launches the app - and even navigates the app if the app is already open (see [this tutorial][1] for more information).

As for the toast notification, you can try and schedule one your remote push notifications server so that it happens to be sent at the same time as the regular reminder, but there are timing issues and you need the remote server. You can't schedule a toast notification for a specific time on the phone (only `Reminder`s and `Alarm`s).

Comment: So I guess I read scheduling long toast notification services for Windows Store Apps. So the scheduling of Toast Notifications can be done only in Win 8 Apps, using Notifications and Dom namespaces.
So I guess for Win Phones you dont have any further options apart from Reminders?.

Comment: Correct, unfortunately there are no other options today.